# Cálculos em PHP

Tags: php

Estou começando em PHP e tenho a seguinte situação. Tenho um valor, resgatado de um banco, e seis botões com os seguintes valores: `+100, +200, +300, +400, +500 e +600`. Como faço para ao clicar em um destes botões, seja feito a soma do valor escolhido através dos botões com o valor resgatado em banco?

**Exemplo:** Eu clico no botão `+500` e o valor resgatado na base é `1.000`. O sistema faz a soma e salva o total.

Comment: Onde é exatamente a sua dúvida? O que você já tentou fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Você terá que fazer algo mais ou menos assim.

```
<?php      


            /*
                aqui esta a parte server-side do seu codigo esta será executada no servidor cada 
               vez que o usuário submeter a pagina.    
            */

            // abra sua conexão
        if(isset($_POST["acao"])&&$_POST["acao"] == "update"){// e verifique qual ação a se fazer
            $valor = $_POST["valor"];
            $update = mysql_query("UPDATE AlgumaTabela SET Valor = '".$valor."' WHERE id=X ");
        }

        // selecione o valor a resgatar do banco de dados      
        $select = mysql_query("SELECT Valor FROM AlgumaTabela WHERE id=X ");
        $valor = 0;
        if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){
            $valor = $row["valor"];
         }
?>    
<html>    
<head>
  <script>
  // função "send" recebe o elemento que você clicou soma o valor resgatado do banco e submete a pagina para o mesmo ser atualizado
  function send(elem){
   var mValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("valor").value);
   document.getElementById("valor").value = mValue+parseInt(elem.value);
    document.getElementById("myform").submit();    
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type='hidden' name="acao" value="update"><!-- campo que contem a ação a ser tomada.-->
    <input type='hidden' name="valor" id="valor"  value="<?php print $valor ?>" ><!-- imprime o valor resgatado do banco para futuras atualizações --->

    <input type="button" onclick="send(this)" value="100">
      <input type="button" onclick="send(this)" value="200">
        <input type="button" onclick="send(this)" value="300">
          <input type="button" onclick="send(this)" value="400">
            <input type="button" onclick="send(this)" value="500">
              <input type="button" onclick="send(this)" value="600">


  </form>  
</body>
```

Comment: Vinicius, o legal é explicar o *porquê* (neste caso, server-side e client-side)... aquela história de dar um peixe ou ensinar a pescar ;)

Comment: Tem razão @brasofilo fiz na pressa mas vou detalhar :)

Comment: Se possível @Tuyoshi já ensina fazendo uso do PDO pq o mysql_* está depreciado.

Answer (score 0):

Você resgata o valor do banco de dados e salva em uma variável, soma o valor do botão com o da variável e faz o update.

```
ao clicar no botão +500:
valor_botao = 500
valor_banco = query("consulta valor no bd")
valor_total = valor_banco + valor_botao
update("valor = valor_total")
```

Se isso não responde sua duvida, tente detalhar.